# How to have Python turtle make an arithmetic spiral?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, spiral

I am new to Turtle but my general plan to make the spiral is to define a recursive function `archSpiral(initialLen, increment, angle, n)` where it does the following sequence `n` times:

1. Draw a line segment of `initialLen`
2. Turn by `angle` degrees
3. And increment the `initialLen` with `increment`

By repeating this sequence over and over it should be able to create a spiral.

However I'm having trouble putting this process into text and so far I have

```py
def archSpiral(initialLen, increment, angle, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        turtle.forward(initialLen)
        turtle.left(angle)
        turtle.foward(initialLen + increment)
```

But it's not working and I'm stuck here.

Comment: Try changing out that second `forward()` command with `initialLen += increment`

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reiterating what Doyousketch2 said:

```py
def archSpiral(initialLen, increment, angle, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        turtle.forward(initialLen)
        turtle.left(angle)
        initialLen += increment
```

Comment: @Doyousketch2, if you want the reputation from this feel free to answer and comment below and I’ll delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to push more of the work onto `range()`:

```
def archSpiral(initialLen, increment, angle, n):
    for length in range(initialLen, initialLen + increment * n, increment):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(angle)
```